# AES Initialization Vector randomization

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to reuse an AES implementation with Initialization Vector. So far I am only implementing the part where data is being encrypted on the android application and being decrypted on the php server. However, the algorithm has a major loophole, that the Initialization Vector is constant, which I just recently found out is a major security flaw. Unfortunately I have already implemented it on every single activity of my application and all scripts on the server side. 
I wanted to know if there was a way to modify this code so that the initialization vector is randomized, and some way to send that vector to the server (or vice versa), so that every time the message is encrypted the pattern keeps changing. Here are my codes for Android and PHP:

Android:

```
package com.fyp.merchantapp;

// This file and its contents have been taken from http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php.html 
//Ownership has been acknowledged

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MCrypt {
static char[] HEX_CHARS = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};

private String iv = "MyNameIsHamza100";//(IV)
private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
private Cipher cipher;

private String SecretKey = "MyNameIsBilal100";//(SECRETKEY)

public MCrypt()
{
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
{
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");

    byte[] encrypted = null;

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return encrypted;
}

public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
{
    if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Empty string");

    byte[] decrypted = null;

    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        //Remove trailing zeroes
        if( decrypted.length > 0)
        {
            int trim = 0;
            for( int i = decrypted.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) if( decrypted[i] == 0 ) trim++;

            if( trim > 0 )
            {
                byte[] newArray = new byte[decrypted.length - trim];
                System.arraycopy(decrypted, 0, newArray, 0, decrypted.length - trim);
                decrypted = newArray;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return decrypted;
}


public static String bytesToHex(byte[] buf)
{
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
    {
        chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}


public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str==null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int len = str.length() / 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}



private static String padString(String source)
{
    char paddingChar = 0;
    int size = 16;
    int x = source.length() % size;
    int padLength = size - x;

    for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
    {
        source += paddingChar;
    }

    return source;
}
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
class MCrypt
{
    private $iv = 'MyNameIsHamza100'; #Same as in JAVA
    private $key = 'MyNameIsBilal100'; #Same as in JAVA
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * @param string $str
     * @param bool $isBinary whether to encrypt as binary or not. Default is: false
     * @return string Encrypted data
     */
    function encrypt($str, $isBinary = false)
    {
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $str = $isBinary ? $str : utf8_decode($str);
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', ' ', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $isBinary ? $encrypted : bin2hex($encrypted);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param bool $isBinary whether to decrypt as binary or not. Default is: false
     * @return string Decrypted data
     */
    function decrypt($code, $isBinary = false)
    {
        $code = $isBinary ? $code : $this->hex2bin($code);
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', ' ', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $isBinary ? trim($decrypted) : utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    }
    protected function hex2bin($hexdata)
    {
        $bindata = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
            $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
        }
        return $bindata;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Generate the IV as a16 byte array using secureRandom() and send the IV with the ciphertext to the server.  Server receives both values and decrypts the data with received IV.  But honestly, not sure why you need this extra layer of encryption over TLS as it seems to add no extra value.

Comment: Oh, great, another Android snippet to fight. Did you know that PHP's mcrypt has been deprecated? And for good reasons.

Comment: Rule number 1: don't "play" with security if you are not an expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: you can simply generate a random IV and *prefix it to the ciphertext*. You need to do this *before* encoding the ciphertext to hexadecimals. Then during decryption first decode, then "remove" the IV bytes, initialize the IV and finally decrypt the ciphertext to obtain the plaintext.

Note that the IV will always be 16 bytes for AES in CBC mode, so there is no direct need to include the IV length anywhere. I used quotes around "remove" as both `IvParameterSpec` as `Cipher.doFinal` accept buffers with offset and length; there is no need to copy the bytes to different arrays.

---

Notes:

- keys should not be strings; lookup PBKDF's such as PBKDF2 to derive a key from a password or pass phrase;
- CBC is generally vulnerable to padding oracle attacks; however, by keeping to PHP's zero padding you may have avoided attacks by accident;
- CBC doesn't provide integrity protection, so note that adversaries may change the ciphertext without decryption failing;
- if the underlying code that uses the text generates errors then you may be vulnerable to plaintext oracle attacks (padding oracle attacks are only part of the larger group of plaintext oracles);
- your Java code is unbalanced; the encrypt and decrypt mode should either perform hex encoding / decoding or they should not;
- the exception handling is of course not good (although that may be just for the example);
- `String#getBytes()` will use UTF-8 on Android, but it may use Windows-1252 on Java SE on Windows, so this is prone to generating the wrong key if you're not careful - always define the character set to use.

---

To use a shared secret to communicate, try TLS in pre-shared secret mode, defined by one of the PSK_ cipher suites.